# App crashes when using onActivityResult(); The problem did not happen before

Tags: android

The app I am making needs data to be transferred from an activity2 to the previous one, activity1. So I am using startActivityForResult() and then onActivityResult();

It was working fine up until yesterday, where my app lags and crashes when I press the button to go from activity1 to activtiy2.

It works again if I comment out onActivityResult() in activity1  for some reason. But then data won't be passed and I need the data from activity2's listview to be transferred to textView in activity1.

I don't believe I have actually changed my code, so I am puzzled to why this have happened. If anyone can help me check my code it will be great. Thank you :)

Crash Log:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.jiowhere, PID: 5667
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.jiowhere.ListViewAdaptor.filter(ListViewAdaptor.java:119)
>           at com.example.jiowhere.ListViewAdaptor.tagFilter(ListViewAdaptor.java:176)
>           at com.example.jiowhere.RecommendationListActivity$2.onTextChanged(RecommendationListActivity.java:96)
>           at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:9754)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5733)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5571)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5528)
>           at com.example.jiowhere.RecommendationListActivity.onActivityResult(RecommendationListActivity.java:145)
>           at com.example.jiowhere.RecommendationListActivity.onClick(RecommendationListActivity.java:161)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
>           at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Activity 1 outside onCreate() Method

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Check that it is the SecondActivity with an OK result
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get String data from Intent
                String returnString = data.getStringExtra("keyName");

                // Set text view with string
                TextView filterView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filterByTags);
                filterView.setText(returnString);
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == tagButton) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TagSystemActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            //crashes app
            onActivityResult(1, RESULT_OK, intent);
        }

    }
```

Activity2 inside OnCreate() method

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String selectedFromList = (String) (listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
                testing.setText(selectedFromList);


                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("keyName", selectedFromList);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();

            }});
```

Comment: post the crash logs - typically examining the logs is 1st step towards debugging the issue

Comment: Hey sorry! Its my first time doing a project on Android Studio so I'm not sure what to expect. I have edited my post. Is that the crash log you are looking for? Thank you very much :)

Comment: it is null at this line `ListViewAdaptor.java:119`, you can check the reason why it is null and fix the problem

Comment: Post your ListViewAdaptor code where exception happens

Comment: from the crash logs its clear that you are getting `null` in your code mostly in Adapter class and then the same `null` seems to be sent back into ActivityResult callback and hence the crash. Put a breakpoint in adapter class on this line ` String selectedFromList = (String) (listView.getItemAtPosition(position)); ` and see in what case it is returning null

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't know Crash Log existed. Managed to debug my problem.

Comment: post your `ListViewAdaptor` code

Answer (score 1):

Remove below line,

```
        onActivityResult(1, RESULT_OK, intent);
```

From here,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == tagButton) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TagSystemActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        //crashes app
        onActivityResult(1, RESULT_OK, intent);
    }
}
```

This line calls activity result with null object before activity2 send result on activity1. You never need to call that method manually.`onActivityResult` method invoke automatically once you get result from somewhere (In your case, from activity2).

Answer (score 0):

String returnString = data.getStringExtra(**"keyName"**);

On this line you need to replace **"keyName"** with your key.
I think the object on null reference on keyName.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to call onActivityResult(...) manually.

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

//crashes app
onActivityResult(1, RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Remove this call to onActivityResult(...); from onClick().

onActivityResult method will be automatically get called when you post result from another activity.